# What good is the create() method?

Tags: 8, dependency-injection, symfony-services

Most classes are instantiated using `create($container)` and `__construct(...$services)` in conjunction, it seems that the more efficient workflow would be to simply pass the container to the constructor `__construct($container)` and not have the create method at all. Is this inherited from Symfony? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: This is not inherited from Symfony. Drupal introduced this factory pattern to instantiate non service classes like controllers and plugins.

Comment: Check out the static keyword for more details.

Comment: I'm not asking how it works. I'm asking what its benefits are. So far the only explanation I've found is that it makes testing easier, but testing without it is also easy.

Comment: This is a question about drupal theory, explicitly in scope in the help center.

Comment: The Help Center also says that questions should be reasonably scoped. Any too-broad question is off-topic, even if the argument is on-topic.

Comment: This is a question I have had since the beginning of drupal 8, and one that there isn't a clear answer to online. I feel that as it pertains to a single pattern used extensively across drupal that it is focused. What make you see it as unfocused?

Comment: I would say that discussing injection patterns is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

The create() __construct() pattern does make testing easier, but not by much. A new container can be very easily generated and populated with the required services for unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

Just my two cents: If you use such a system it is not needed to set the required services in a service.yml but you can easily set, overlook and check the services in the class itself - in the create() method, where you define all the services. I find this more comfortable than writing everything in a YAML file